# Finding the size of a file stream using file descriptors in C

Tags: c, http, file-descriptor

As a school assignment, I'm writing a simple HTTP webserver in C.
I have most of the code ready to go, but `send()`/`write()` requires the length of the message to be sent.

This is where I'm struggling. `fseek()` doesn't work and so `ftell()` returns an "Illegal seek" `errno`. After identifying the method and retrieving the correct response code, I use `fprintf()` to write directly to the file stream.

```
static void response(FILE *response, int code, char *path, int fd)
{
    FILE *body;
    char *line = makestring(300) //Creates an empty string of size 300

    ... // Replace code in between with other code block

    if(code == 200){
        http_ok(response); //A function with fprintf's to write the headers.
        body = fopen(path, "w");

        while(!feof(body)){
            fgets(line, 300, body);
            fprintf(response, "%s\r\n", line);
        }

    fclose(body);
    }

    ... // Replace up to this point

fseek(response, 0L, SEEK_END);
int response_size = ftell(response);
rewind(response);

send(fd, response, response_size, 0);
}
```

Now, this is a simplified version of my code, including only the status 200.
The thing is here the response is returned properly, and the page opens in the browser. However, the `response_size` variable always prints to `-1`.

Now proceeding the the status code 301 Moved Permanently, it's not working at all. This code can go as a replacement for the other `if`-statement between the two "..."s

```
...
if(code == 301){
    http_moved(response, path);
}
...
```

The http-functions have a general look like this

```
void http_ok/moved(FILE *response)
{
    fprintf(response, "Correct codes and headers for the response type here\r\n")
    ...
    fprintf(response, "\r\n\r\n")
}
```

The response `FILE` is opened on the socket's file descriptor using `fdopen(sockfd, "w")`, so it's not a normal `fopen()`. As far as my understanding goes, this means `fseek()` won't work as intended.

As for the question itself, how can I get the proper length of the http response when I'm using the file descriptors?

Comment: Note: Change `while(!feof(body)){ fgets(line, 300, body);` to `while (1) { if (fgets(line, 300, body) == NULL) break;`.  IOW, use the return value of `fgets()` rather than `feof()`.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think of that possibility. Didn't relate to the issue though, but thanks anyways :)

Comment: @chux: why not `while (fgets(line, 300, body) != NULL) { … }`?

Comment: `fprintf(response, "%s\r\n", line);` Adding extra "\r\n" is not needed, `fgets()` keeps the "\r\n" . : can keep a running count of characters in the first loop (*you wrote them*) ; no need to seek to file-end and ftell to obtain the file size.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler  `while (fgets(line, 300, body) != NULL) { … }`  is an even better style.  My comment focused on the use of return value of `fgets()` vs. `feof()` with minimal layout change.

Comment: If you `int response_size = -1; while (fgets(line, 300, body) != NULL) { response_size = ftell(response); … }`, does response_size ever become `-1`?  Maybe `fseek()` is having trouble after the `EOF` condition occurs?

Comment: `The response FILE is opened on the socket's file descriptor using fdopen(sockfd, "w"), so it's not a normal fopen(). As far as my understanding goes, this means fseek() won't work as intended.` That's absolutely correct. `fseek` won't work and `rewind` won't work. Why are you even trying? Also, why are you writing the response size *after* the response? Also, use `fread` and `fwrite`, not `fgets` and `fprintf`, as you are sending a file that is not necessarily text. If you want to know its size beforehand, `fseek` and `ftell` the *body*.

Comment: It is not clear what is being asked here. You don't need to get the size from the file descriptor that your HTTP header is outputting to. You need to know the size of what you're putting there, so you can publish the appropriate value in the content size header to the client.  Sometimes this is hard to know in advance, like when you have dynamic content produced by scripts or whatever; in that case you don't have the header. The header is valuable for large file transfers, though; clients can report download progress in their UI and such.

Comment: The response file which you opened with `fopen` does  have a size. Calculate the size and pass it as an argument to the `http_ok/moved` function; it can then generate the transfer size header. A value of -1 could mean "size unknown; don't generate header". (By the way, what C dialect are you using that allows slashes in identifiers?)

Comment: @Kaz according to the `send()` man pages, I have to give it a size of the message to be transmitted. And as far as I've understood, it should be the size of the complete message. Headers and everything. 
By the way, the `http_ok/moved` is just a template mockup to describe the basic layout of the different response functions I've written. In reality, there's a `http_ok` and a `http_moved`.

Comment: "according to the send() man pages, I have to give it a size of the message to be transmitted". With TCP you transmit a stream of bytes, fragment by fragment. You give `send()` a size of each fragment. This fragmentation is irrelevant to the application on the other side, it receives a stream of bytes. You don't have to `send()` the entire HTTP message at once.

Answer (score 0):

If response is guaranteed to point to a file, I would use:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

struct stat st;

if (fstat(fileno(response)), &st) == -1) {
    /* handle error */
} else {
     response_size = (int)st.st_size;
}
```